# Android : Binding to update UI

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

In my android application, I have below classes. I want to bind these classes in UI to display the UI content based on object data.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="itemContainerInformation" type="com.myApp.Models.ItemsContainerInformation"/>
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    tools:context="com.myApp.Fragments.DetailedViewFragment"
    android:id="@+id/layout_detailed_view">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{itemInformation.t1Caption}"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/textView_day_t1_header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_date_header"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.currentDateHeaderCaption}"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/textView_date_header"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_information"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_day_t1_header"
    android:background="@color/fall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_day_information_list"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[0].Caption}"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information1"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[1].Caption}"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information2"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[2].Caption}"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information3"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[3].Caption}"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information4"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[4].Caption}"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information5"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information6"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_day"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="0dp" >
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linear_layout_day_information_list"
        android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.currentDate}"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/textView_day"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_information_bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_information"
    android:background="@color/fall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[5].Caption}"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/textView_day_information_bottom1"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[6].Caption}"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/textView_day_information_bottom2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_day_information_bottom1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ItemInformation.java**

```
public class ItemInformation extends BaseObservable {
private String caption;
private int lineIndex;
private int lineFontSize;
private int lineFontColor;
private int lineIndentation;
private int imageIndex;

public ItemInformation()
{

}

@Bindable
public String getCaption() {    return caption;    }

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.caption);
}

@Bindable
public int getLineIndex() {     return lineIndex;    }

public void setLineIndex(int lineIndex) {
    this.lineIndex = lineIndex;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lineIndex);
}

@Bindable
public int getLineFontSize() {     return lineFontSize;    }

public void setLineFontSize(int lineFontSize) {
    this.lineFontSize = lineFontSize;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lineFontSize);
}

@Bindable
public int getLineFontColor() {     return lineFontColor;    }

public void setLineFontColor(int lineFontColor) {
    this.lineFontColor = lineFontColor;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lineFontColor);
}

@Bindable
public int getLineIndentation() {     return lineIndentation;    }

public void setLineIndentation(int lineIndentation) {
    this.lineIndentation = lineIndentation;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lineIndentation);
}

@Bindable
public int getImageIndex() {     return imageIndex;    }

public void setImageIndex(int imageIndex) {
    this.imageIndex = imageIndex;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.imageIndex);}



public static int GetColorInformation(String fontcolor)
{
    return  Color.parseColor(fontcolor);
    //int desiredColour = getResources().getColor(getResources().getIdentifier("my_color", "color"
}
}
```

**ItemContainerInformation.java**

```
public class ItemContainerInformation extends BaseObservable {
private List<ItemInformation> itemInformations = new ArrayList<ItemInformation>();

private String currentDate;
private String currentDateHeaderCaption;
private String t1Caption;
private int rowIndex;
private int columnIndex;

private int currentMonth;
private int currentYear;

public ItemContainerInformation()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}

public ItemContainerInformation(String currentDate) {

    this.currentDate = currentDate;
}

@Bindable
public String getCurrentDate() {
    return currentDate;
}

public void setCurrentDate(String currentDate) {
    this.currentDate = currentDate;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.currentDate);
}

@Bindable
public String getCurrentDateHeaderCaption() {
    return currentDateHeaderCaption;
}

public void setCurrentDateHeaderCaption(String currentDateHeaderCaption) {
    this.currentDateHeaderCaption = currentDateHeaderCaption;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.currentDateHeaderCaption);
}

@Bindable
public String getT1Caption() {
    return t1Caption;
}

public void setT1Caption(String t1Caption) {
    this.t1Caption = t1Caption;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.t1Caption);
}

@Bindable
public int getRowIndex() {
    return rowIndex;
}

public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
    this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.rowIndex);
}

@Bindable
public int getColumnIndex() {
    return columnIndex;
}

public void setColumnIndex(int columnIndex) {
    this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.columnIndex);
}

@Bindable
public int getCurrentMonth() {
    return currentMonth;
}

public void setCurrentMonth(int currentMonth) {
    this.currentMonth = currentMonth;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.currentMonth);
}

@Bindable
public int getCurrentYear() {
    return currentYear;
}

public void setCurrentYear(int currentYear) {
    this.currentYear = currentYear;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.currentYear);
}


@Bindable
public List<ItemInformation> getItemInformations() {
    return itemInformations;
}

public void setItemInformations(List<ItemInformation> itemInformations) {
    this.itemInformations = itemInformations;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.itemInformations);
}
}
```

**DetailedViewFagment**

```
public class DetailedViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ItemContainerInformation currentInormationItem;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detailed_view, container, false);


        if(currentInormationItem == null)
        {
            currentInormationItem = new ItemContainerInformation("100");

            List<ItemInformation> dailyItems = new ArrayList<ItemInformation>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ItemInformation item = new ItemInformation();
                item.setCaption("Caption_");

                dailyItems.add(item);
            }

            currentDayInormationItem.setItemInformations(dailyItems);
        }


        FragmentDetailedDayViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_detailed_view, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        //here data must be an instance of the class MarsDataProvider
        binding.setDateInformation(currentDayInormationItem);

        return v;
    }

    // This method is used to update the object from 'ParentItem'
    // So when a UI click happens in the ParentFragment this method is called from ParentFragment
    // which updates the objects. Now this updated object () will have new values which i want to update in the UI inside detailed view fragment.
    public void UpdateDetailedDayView(DateInformation dayInormationItem)
    {
        // Should update all textviews in the child view but not working???
        currentDayInormationItem = dayInormationItem;
    }

}
```

**ParentViewFragment**

```
public class ParentViewFragment extends Fragment {

// This is inside the parent fragment class which has multiple items populated using Adapter and ViewHolder
// On item click of the UI i want to update the 'DetailedViewFragment'.
MyRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(ItemInformation itemInformation) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked --- " + itemInformation.getCurrentDate(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // On click i am creating new fragment and updating it
                DetailedViewFragment detailedView = new DetailedViewFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.month_detailed_view_container, detailedView).commit();

                detailedView.UpdateDetailedDayView(itemInformation);
            }
        };


}
```

Basically i have different textviews in UI and respective UI properties are stored in object like indentation, foreground color, font size etc. *How I can bind this information to a textview?*

I am not able to view the text using this line, can someone help me to correct my mistake in the below line and display the text using the specific identation and forground color.

**android:text="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[0].Caption}"**

*How I can bind the object and update the UI based on  object data?*

Thanks.

Comment: can you post code of your activity/fragment where you have binded this view

Comment: Have you tried binding the attributes associated with the setters? e.g. `android:foreground="@{itemContainerInformation.itemInformations[0].lineColor}"`

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMount.
I tried for other properties also but its not working for any properties in that class. I have updated the code above, let me know if you find any other mistake in my code.

Comment: Are you seeing an error? If so, what error? If not, are you just not seeing changes? I suspect that the problem is that your code returns List<T> instead of ObservableList<T>. Since data binding is generated and does not use runtime type analysis, you won't see changes in the `itemInformations` list reflected in the UI.

Comment: I am not able to see any text in the UI. I tried changing as you suggested but that also didnt worked for me. Here is what i tried changing...



`private ObservableList<ItemInformation> itemInformations = new ObservableArrayList<ItemInformation>();`

Any other suggestion which i can try...